# Architecture of application with public RESTful API + local access to API

Tags: php, rest, api, design-patterns, restful-architecture

I'm planning a small web application project which will consist of both a website (using PHP) and in the future a mobile application. I want to implement a RESTful API (using PHP) to communicate with the mobile app. But since the API and the website will both be written in PHP and hosted on the same server, it seems a bit odd to make HTTP calls from the website to the public API (or isn't it)?

Anyway, I am considering putting a layer between the API and the business logic, basically just consisting of an object that exposes the same API as the public RESTful API, but as a PHP object that can be accessed directly from the website.

1. Is this a good or bad idea? Why?
2. Is this a well known pattern? If so, what is it called?

I found some sites proposing a similar structure and calling it "API Gateway Object", but I'm not sure if that is an actual well-known pattern or just something they came up with tho.

Here's a sketch of what I have in mind:

[image: Application structure]

Comment: What advantage do you see in the Gateway Object, as opposed to communicating directly from the Presentation and ReST layers to the Business layer?

Answer (score 1):

Good question (answer) ... not sure it is the right kind for this site. I use exactly that pattern, which I ended up rolling out after hard-fought battles with other architectural approaches/frameworks i.e. I dont know its name.

some pros :

- Turns out it is also extremely useful for testing, climbing up the abstraction ladder can be easily structured and exercised with your favorite testing toys.
- Your mobile data architecture can be a straight isomorph of the Gateway Object model.
- It nicely decouples for straight php access AND it still permits you to keep some things in play when it matters : auth, logging, traceability of database access.
- It future proofs your design : although it may seem silly at the moment, you may find that you will eventually need to have www and mobile presentations served from different instances. Migrating your php presentation to use RESTful API will be a cinch if you do this right.

An example : Say I have a `Message` object, this object will have a number of 'normal' classes:

- Message : the plain-old-php-object, no side effects, no persistence
- MessageDAO : the persistence manager for Message. basic CRUD, no business logic, just elementary CRUD
- MessageWF : the workflows offered by the business logic
- IBMessageSpec : a specification for a message
- OBMessage : the representation of the message that I wish to send to the caller

I use a DI container to inject in each of the above the specifics of the context.

In my Mobile , I have OBMessageSpec wihch is essentially an IBMessageSpec, and IBMessage which maps the servers's OBMessage. That code is pretty much re-useable to multiple instance types, and apps.

Answer (score 1):

It is OK idea. You could provide an API for internal PHP usage via some `API Gateway Object` and expose `RESTful API`, that uses same `API Gateway Object`. It may be named `Adapter`, because it adapts your php API to be used by external services via HTTP.

**But** why do you need something to be known pattern to use it ? It perfectly lays on your needs, this architecture allows you to keep your modules consistent and avoid duplications of logic.

You can use RESTful on PHP side, it would be slower, but more flexible - maybe in future you'll need to rewrite backend with some other language - you don't need to change frontend!

So, it is up to you to decide, what is more preferable for you, it is not about patterns.